# How to output all sub-folder to a drop down list in a HTA?

Tags: vbscript

I have a code like below. I want to output all sub-folder in K:\work to the drop down list in this HTA. Because all sub-folder in k:\work change all the time. so every time i click drop down list, it need to have the latest contents. is that possible to do this based on my code?
and also when I select new customer, I need to have a popup window allowing me to enter the name and create a new folder.

In my code i only have 1 drop down list. I need to have 7 drop down lists in this HTA, all with same concept that can create new folder if doesn't exist.
The file structure like this:
K:\CUSTOMER\DESIGN\DETAIL\ORDER......
Each drop down list will output one level of sub-folder, if I select a folder from upper level in the drop down list, the rest of drop down list will be auto-changed to the sub-folder in that parent folder.
Can any1 help me?

---

```
<HEAD>
<TITLE>K Drive Program Structure</TITLE>
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="AIDS" 
APPLICATIONNAME="K Drive Program Structure" 
BORDER="Dialog"
CAPTION="Yes"
SCROLL="NO"
SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
SYSMENU="Yes"
WINDOWSTATE="maximize">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">

Sub Window_OnLoad
Window.Site.Focus
End Sub

Sub btn01_OnClick
Dim strProduct

oElements = Window.Site.SelectedIndex
strProduct = Window.Site.Options(oElements).Text

Select Case strProduct
    Case "AMCAN HONSEL"
        MsgBox "You selected AMCAN HONSEL",64,"Selection"
    Case "CHRYSLER ETOBICOKE"
        MsgBox "You selected CHRYSLER ETOBICOKE",64,"Selection"
    Case "CHRYSLER KOKOMO"
        MsgBox "You selected CHRYSLER KOKOMO",64,"Selection"
    Case "GM POWERTRAIN"
        MsgBox "You selected GM POWERTRAIN",64,"Selection"
    Case "MERCEDES BENZ"
        MsgBox "You selected MERCEDES BENZ",64,"Selection"
    Case "NEMAK"
        MsgBox "You selected NEMAK",64,"Selection"
    Case "NEW CUSTOMER"
        MsgBox "You selected NEW CUSTOMER",64,"Selection"
End Select

End Sub

Sub btn02_OnClick
Window.Close
End Sub
</SCRIPT>

<H2>K Drive Structure</H2>
<P>Please select or create: 
<SELECT NAME="Site">
<OPTION>AMCAN HONSEL</OPTION>
<OPTION>CHRYSLER ETOBICOKE</OPTION>
<OPTION>CHRYSLER KOKOMO</OPTION>
<OPTION>GM POWERTRAIN</OPTION>
<OPTION>MERCEDES BENZ</OPTION>
<OPTION>NEMAK</OPTION>
<OPTION>NEW CUSTOMER</OPTION>
</SELECT><P>

<BR>
<BR>
<Input Type = "Button" Name = "btn01" VALUE = "SUBMIT">
<Input Type = "Button" Name = "btn02" VALUE = "CLOSE">
<BR>
<BR>

</BODY>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill a dropdown list in an HTA like this:

```
Sub UpdateList
  For Each opt In list.Options
    opt.RemoveNode
  Next

  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  For Each f In fso.GetFolder("K:\work").SubFolders
    Set opt = document.createElement("OPTION")
    opt.Text  = f.Name
    opt.Value = f.Path
    list.Add(opt)
  Next
End Sub
```

The HTML tag for the dropdown list should look like this:

```
<select id="list" name="list" onMouseOver="UpdateList"></select>
```

However, building a directory browser with dropdown lists doesn't strike me as such a hot idea. Any particular reason why you can't use the [`Shell.BrowseForFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774065) method?

```
Set os = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

basedir = os.Namespace("K:\work").Self.Path
Set fldr = os.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select folder:", &h10&, basedir)
```

What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?