# Create Sub-folder list when dropdown option is selected

Tags: vbscript, hta

I have a HTA code below which list all sub-folder in a specific folder.
My question is that if I click one sub-folder from list, how can it auto-create the second list that gives me all child-folder in that sub-folder? and so on till there is no more child-folder found, the last child-folder needs to list all files in it. Also how can I add a extra option in the end of each list called [new folder] that will pop-up a window allowing enter the name to create a new folder.

In the end if click [submit] button, It will open the last child-folder I choose in windows explorer.
I am new to vbs, so please help

---

```
<HEAD>
  <TITLE>K Drive Program Structure</TITLE>
  <HTA:APPLICATION ID="Hello" 
    APPLICATIONNAME="K Drive Program Structure" 
    BORDER="Dialog"
    CAPTION="Yes"
    SCROLL="NO"
    SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
    SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
    SYSMENU="Yes"
    WINDOWSTATE="maximize">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">

Sub UpdateList
  For Each opt In list.Options
    opt.RemoveNode
  Next

  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  For Each f In fso.GetFolder("K:\AppData").SubFolders
    Set opt = document.createElement("OPTION")
    opt.Text  = f.Name
    opt.Value = f.Path
    list.Add(opt)
  Next
End Sub
</SCRIPT>

<H2>K Drive Structure</H2>
<P>CUSTOMER
<select id="list" name="list" onMouseOver="UpdateList"></select><P>

<BR>
<BR>
<Input Type = "Button" Name = "btn01" VALUE = "SUBMIT">
<Input Type = "Button" Name = "btn02" VALUE = "CLOSE">
<BR>
<BR>

</BODY>
```

---

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using the `Shell.BrowseForFolder` method like I [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17242252/1630171)? Trying to re-invent it in HTA will always be awkward.

As for your question, you need to add an `onChange` handler to the `<select>` tag:

```
<select id="list" name="list" onMouseOver="UpdateList" onChange="EnumSubFolders">
</select>
```

and a procedure `EnumSubFolders` to enumerate the child folders:

```
Sub EnumSubFolders
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  For Each opt In list.options
    If opt.selected Then
      Set sf = fso.GetFolder(opt.value).SubFolders
      'do stuff with sf
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

You may need to apply some modifications to `UpdateList`, too (like remembering the currently selected option before refreshing the list).