# hta vbs populate drop down menu with files in folder

Tags: drop-down-menu, vbscript, onload, hta, auto-populate

Using an Onload command I can output the relevant files from a folder in a messagebox but cannot understand how to use that information to populate a drop down menu in the html code.

```
Sub Window_onLoad
    LoadDropDown
End Sub

Sub LoadDropDown
    Dim dir, foundFile
    dir = zipfolder
    Dim fileNames, fso, folder
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(dir)
    For Each foundFile In folder.Files
        fileNames = foundFile.name
        If(Right(fileNames,4) = ".zip") then
        fileNames = Left(fileNames,(Len(fileNames)-4))
        Value = Value & fileNames & vbCr 
        MsgBox "inside sub Value : " & Value
    End If 
    Next
End Sub
```

This will display a msgbox for each file found with extension ".zip"

The confusing part is how to display this information (on load) in a drop down menu???
What am I missing from the below?

```
<select id="test" name="test" onchange="LoadDropDown" style="width: 336px;">
        <option value=""></option>
        </select>
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

This is NOT the same as:
[How to output all sub-folder to a drop down list in a HTA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241275/how-to-output-all-sub-folder-to-a-drop-down-list-in-a-hta)
They are not using a file filter and mouseover on populate is NOT what is required or even wanted.

Comment: You pull a list of files but you don't tell it to populate the dropdown, what's confusing about that? If your not familiar with working with the DOM suggest you start with `Set dropdown = document.getElementById("test")`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to output all sub-folder to a drop down list in a HTA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241275/how-to-output-all-sub-folder-to-a-drop-down-list-in-a-hta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this to auto-populate your drop down menu :

I have tested this in the temporary folder to populate `*.tmp` files, so you can change it for your needs

```
<html>
<HTA:APPLICATION ICON="magnify.exe"/>
<head>
<Title>Load DropDown Menu</Title>
<script language="vbscript">
Option Explicit
Dim ws,Temp,dir,objOption,Ext
Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Temp = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
Dir = Temp
Ext = "tmp"
'---------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Window_onLoad
    Call LoadDropDown(Dir,Ext)
End Sub
'---------------------------------------------------------------
Sub LoadDropDown(Dir,Ext)
Dim fso,folder,foundFile,fileNames,objOption,Count
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(Dir)
Count = 0
Call ClearListbox()
For Each foundFile In folder.Files
    fileNames = FSO.GetBaseName(foundFile)
    if Lcase(fso.getExtensionName(foundFile.path)) = Lcase(Ext) then
        Count = Count + 1
        Set objOption = Document.createElement("OPTION")
        objOption.Text =  Count & " - " & fileNames 
        objOption.Value = foundFile.path
        DropDown.Add(objOption) 
    End If 
Next  
End Sub
'---------------------------------------------------------------
Sub ClearListbox()
    For Each objOption in DropDown.Options
        objOption.RemoveNode
    Next 
End Sub
'---------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Explorer(File)
    MsgBox File
    ws.run "Explorer /n,/select,"& File &"",1,True
End Sub
'---------------------------------------------------------------
</script>
</head>
<select id="DropDown" name="DropDown" onchange="Explorer(DropDown.value)" style="width: 336px;">
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Based on your last comment

> How can i add more than extension file in the dropdown listbox ?

```
<html>
<HTA:APPLICATION ICON="magnify.exe"/>
<head>
<Title>Load DropDown Menu</Title>
<script language="vbscript">
Option Explicit
Dim ws,Temp,dir,objOption,ArrayExtensions,Ext
Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Temp = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
Dir = Temp
ArrayExtensions = Array("exe","bat","cmd","vbs","ps1","zip","rar","tmp")
'---------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Window_onLoad
    Call ClearListbox()
    For each Ext in ArrayExtensions
        Call LoadDropDown(Dir,Ext)
    Next
End Sub
'---------------------------------------------------------------
Sub LoadDropDown(Dir,Ext)
Dim fso,folder,foundFile,fileNames,objOption,Count
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(Dir)
Count = 0
For Each foundFile In folder.Files
    fileNames = FSO.GetBaseName(foundFile)
    if Lcase(fso.getExtensionName(foundFile.path)) = Lcase(Ext) then
        Count = Count + 1
        Set objOption = Document.createElement("OPTION")
        objOption.Text =  "[" & Ext & "] - " & Count & " - " & foundFile.Name 
        objOption.Value = foundFile.path
        DropDown.Add(objOption) 
    End If 
Next  
End Sub
'---------------------------------------------------------------
Sub ClearListbox()
    For Each objOption in DropDown.Options
        objOption.RemoveNode
    Next 
End Sub
'---------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Explorer(File)
    MsgBox File
    ws.run "Explorer /n,/select,"& File &"",1,True
End Sub
'---------------------------------------------------------------
</script>
</head>
<select id="DropDown" name="DropDown" onchange="Explorer(DropDown.value)" style="width: 336px;">
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is brilliant Hackoo. Just had to change the global variables to suit my needs as you advised, Temp, Dir and Ext and it works flawlessly!! 
To remove the count number, just delete the "count = count + 1" and  remove count from the:
objOption.Text line ?

Comment: `For Each foundFile In folder.Files
    fileNames = FSO.GetBaseName(foundFile)
    if Lcase(fso.getExtensionName(foundFile.path)) = Lcase(Ext) then
        'Count = Count + 1
        Set objOption = Document.createElement("OPTION")
        objOption.Text =  fileNames 
        objOption.Value = foundFile.path
        DropDown.Add(objOption) 
    End If 
Next`

Comment: I just commented out the count line and ammended the  objOption.Text line.

Comment: Hackoo there is one part of the code that I need to change.

The output value = full dir name + file.ext
How would i change this to just "file.ext" and remove the entire path from the value?

Comment: You should write like this Foundfile.name

Comment: If I wanted to add another extension (or more) to the same drop down list, which part of the code would need to be ammended? Thank you!

Comment: @PCTipsnTricks In this case you should make an array of extensions, check my last edit code !

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
<html>
<head>

<script language="vbscript">

Sub Init
    document.getElementById("option1").innerText = "Sample 1"
    document.getElementById("option2").innerText = "Sample 2"
End Sub

</script>

</head>
<body onLoad="Init()">

<select id="test" name="test" style="width: 336px;">
    <option id="option1"></option>
    <option id="option2"></option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```